# How to check if set exists in java?

Tags: java, set, treeset

I am looping through some strings and i want to add each string to the appropriate set using java treeset.How can i check if treeset exists?My code should look similiar to this:

```
if (set exists)
set.add(string)
else{
    TreeSet<Integer> tree = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    tree.add(string)    
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could provide a complete example.

Comment: @BerkKarabacak you need to define a set variable before you can add stuff to it.

Comment: You could always go for exception catching. But that sounds like strange design. Saying strange not bad because sometimes you're forced into such things that should be avoided.

Comment: My sets were not defined before.So i cannot use !=null.Is there a way to define hundreds of set using  loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewher in your code you will have a variable called `set` of type TreeSet or Set

```
if (set != null ){
   set.add(string)
}else{
    set = new TreeSet<String>(); // it's not set if integers but Strings 
    tree.add(string)    
}
```